# Google Search console noindex and property errors

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I'm having a series of problems with Google Search Console and I'm finding it hard to fix.

My site is set as a Domain Property, everything works fairly well, except at some point about a month and a half ago I marked a new page as "noindex", google crawled it and is now displaying an error.

I tried verifying it but the fix has been pending now for more than a month and I'm unsure if there's something wrong or if I should wait more.

I then tried to access the Google analytics Search Console integration, however as far as I understand it this does not work unless I create a new URL property in Search Console for my site.

Once I did this, that URL property displayed a fair amount of noindex errors for many pages that are fine on the Domain Property. However all those pages were indexed and searchable on Google.

What should I do in this case? I need to use the URL Remover tool, but it is also not available for Domain Properties.

Comment: `I marked a new page as "noindex"` - Was this intentional? How did you "mark" the page? "google crawled it and is now displaying an error." - What is the "error"? "I tried verifying it but the fix has been pending now" - What do you mean by this? Did you try resubmitting the URL to the index? "noindex errors for many pages" - What do you mean exactly? Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a robot.txt file for pages you do not want to be scrolled by search engines.

Then go back to Google search console https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6078399?hl=en . Check if your robot.txt is correct.

Ask Google to recrawl your URLs. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289.

Although the documentation states that it can take from a few days to weeks, usually, it goes pretty fast in a matter of days that Google's search engine indexes your page again.

Also, have you checked for your metatag for 'noindex' if there is a typo?  It would be good, as docroot also mentioned that you show us your errors and how you coded your heading.